# Star Trek Voyager : Episode Scorpion, Red alert music when 8472 attack the Borg

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, borg

I know this is an unusual question, I hope it is not closed. I am looking specifically for the ringtone used in series Star trek Voyager, episode Scorpion. It happens when 7of9, Janeway and Tuvok are on the Borg cube and species 8472 are closing in.

At that time, there is a Red Alert. Does anyone know where I can get the audio file. I searched it on net and only came up with the below YouTube video which is just of 4 seconds.

A slightly longer scene with the same red alert sound can be heard [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bkw69E_C4g&feature=youtu.be&t=103)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: There are software apps for making your own ringtones. I'm sure you could just record the sound yourself, or extract it from a video/audio clip, and make a ringtone from it.

Comment: You mean you're looking for a ringtone of the sound that was used.  They didn't use a ringtone in the episode. :P

Comment: @RemyLebeau : If you can make it, I offer you a bounty.. ;-)

Comment: @Joachim : Seriously, I thought you saw 7, Janeway, Tuvok taking a selfie and Tuvok complaining selfies are illogical. Watch the episode again my friend.. :P

Comment: @RemyLebeau : There is some other noise, the only reason why I just copied that video

Comment: Just clarifying: that video you've linked us to is *the* sound you're after?

Comment: @N_Soong : Yes, but it has background noise and is not consistent.

Comment: @WeareBorg I've just edited my question with a new sound clip that might be of interest to you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the Borg Red Alert signal.
You can find it, along Yellow alert one in Star Trek: Starfleet Command 3 game [here](http://mediafire.com/listen/amffcrw5r3pexmi/ALredBorg.mp3)

Comment: Could you provide a link where one can find it?

Comment: This is the game: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Starfleet_Command_III  . If you want the sound files themselves, I could extract them from the game's res files.

Comment: Just be mindful of the copyright associated with that 

Comment: @N_Soong : Will they sue me? The economics of 24th century work differently, see, money doesn't exist anymore. - Captn Jean Luc Picard.

Comment: @Overmind : I am waiting for you man.. Thanks.. ;-)

Comment: Here's the link to the audio file extracted from SFC3: http://www.mediafire.com/listen/amffcrw5r3pexmi/ALredBorg.mp3

Answer (score 3):

I haven't been able to find that *exact* sound, but the following should be fairly close:

- [Deep Space 9 Alert](http://www.trekcore.com/audio/redalertandklaxons/ds9_red_alert2.mp3) (probably the closest)
- [Computer Alert](http://www.trekcore.com/audio/computer/alert07.mp3)
- [Another Computer Alert](http://www.trekcore.com/audio/computer/alert09.mp3)
- [Voyager Blue Alert](http://www.trekcore.com/audio/redalertandklaxons/voybluealert.mp3)

All of the above have been sourced from [TrekCore](http://www.trekcore.com/audio/); if none of these are quite what you are looking for, you're bound to find another excellent sound there - they have a fantastic repository!

As for the exact sound, I have taken the liberty of generating an mp3 file for you, which can be found [here](http://www.filedropper.com/borgredalert).  As I say, it's taken directly from the video in the original question, but probably will suffice for a ringtone.

As for making a ringtone, I'm not sure what operating system you're running, but hopefully these mp3 files will be of use!  If it's an iPhone, try [these instructions for using iTunes](http://www.techhive.com/article/156234/Turn_Any_MP3_into_an_iPhone_Ringtone.html)

Comment: Blue alert is beautiful :D

Comment: heh I just came on to write that then realised someone already had then realised it was me